# String format and vararg in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, variadic-functions, android-context

I have the following method

```
fun formatMessages(indicators: IntArray): CharSequence {
    return context.getString(R.string.foo, indicators)
}
```

And the string is:

```
<string name="foo">$1%d - $2%d range of difference</string>
```

I get a complaint from Android Studio that:
`Wrong argument count, format string requires 2 but format call supplies 1`

What I am really trying to accomplish is to be able to pass to such a `formatMessages` any number of indicators `(1,2,3..)` and the proper string would be selected/displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your function to this:

```
fun formatMessages(indicators: IntArray): CharSequence {
    return context.getString(R.string.foo, indicators[0], indicators[1])
}
```

But of course you need a proper checking that indicators length is at least 2 so it will not crash.

Reason for this is `getString(int resId, Object... formatArgs)` runtime will fail because it expects 2 parameters from what is defined in the string resource.

Comment: So basically although `getString` gets and array, the string passed in *must* match the actual number of arguments provided?

Comment: Yes that is right. Compiler recognises that and is requiring you to match the number of arguments from the string resource. `Object... formatArgs` is varargs and not equal to `Object[]`.

Comment: I changed `indicators: IntArray` to `vararg indicators: Int` but I still get the same error. Shouldn't that be acceptable?

Comment: For some reason, compiler does not let you do that. But if you still want to force doing this, there is hacky way to do it. And this means this is not advisable.

    
```fun formatMessagesHack(resourceId: Int, indicators: IntArray): CharSequence {
        return context.getString(resourceId, indicators)
    }```

This way, the compiler doesn't know what specific resource are you trying to format.

Answer (score 0):

> [When we call a vararg-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g. asList(1, 2, 3), or, if we already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, we use the spread operator (prefix the array with *):](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs)

```
fun formatMessages(indicators: Array<Object>): CharSequence {
    return context.getString(R.string.foo, *indicators)
}
```

If you need `indicators` to have type `IntArray`, you'll have to convert it:

```
fun formatMessages(indicators: IntArray): CharSequence {
    return context.getString(R.string.foo, *(Array<Object>(indicators.size) { indicators[it] }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Feb 2024**
Unfortunately, Kotlin's `String.format` function doesn't directly accept **vararg** parameters. We have to pass the arguments separately.

But, there is way to achieve the desired outcome, `format2` function, convert the **vararg** argument to an **Array** and then pass it to `String.format` :

```
fun String.Companion.format2(format: String, vararg formatArgs: Any?): String {
    val arguments = arrayOfNulls<Any?>(formatArgs.size)
    formatArgs.copyInto(arguments)
    return String.format(format, *arguments)
}
```